# Invoke-Command Arguments not being passed properly

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find and read specific events in the event log on a remote server using `Invoke-Command` (so I can pass credentials that are already stored as a variable) as such:

```powershell
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $serverName -ArgumentList $zone -ScriptBlock {
Get-EventLog -LogName "DNS Server" -Newest 20 | 
Where-Object { $_.message -match $args[0]} | Format-List } -Credential $Credential
```

My `-message` search text is not being passed properly. This works if I replace `$args[0]` with a valid string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you use "args" in a nested script block, put it in another variable. `$a = $args[0]`

Comment: Thank you - that worked perfectly.  So much to learn.